# Change variable value inside a variable in PHP

Tags: php

I had wondered this for a long time without being able to solve it.

We have an HTML structure inside a few variables
    $X = '*some HTML*'.$a.'*more HTML*'.$b.'*more HTML*'.$c.'*more HTML*';
    $Y = '*some HTML*'.$a.'*more HTML*'.$c.'*more HTML*';
    $Z = '*some HTML*'.$a.'*more HTML*'.$b.'*more HTML*'.$d.'*more HTML*';

And when the PHP "*chooses*" which **mayus var**(X,Y,Z) to use: I would like change the value of the inside variables(a,b,c,d...) for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign your "mayus var" (whatever that means) the value is not dynamic. Once it's set it set, until you change it. If you want to generate this value dynamically, you can use a function instead of a variable.

```
function x($a, $b, $c, $d){
    return 'some HTML'.$a.'more HTML'.$b.'more HTML'.$d.'more HTML';
}

echo x("h", "e", "l", "o");
```

Comment: ¡Excelent! You had saved me a ton of stuff; I had never used functions in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Once you assign that value to $X, PHP has evaluated all the variables on the right-hand side and they are simply strings. Assuming that choosing X is not an expensive process,

```
if ( conditionsForChoosingX() ) {
    $a = "new a";  // and so on
}

$X = 'some HTML'.$a.'more HTML'.$b.'more HTML'.$c.'more HTML';
```